# UnboundLocalError while executing Py script in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am getting below error while executing the below py script. I really appreciate if anyone can help me on this.

```
[ERROR] UnboundLocalError: local variable 'get_object' referenced before assignment 
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 28, in lambda_handler
   readObj = get_object(waf_bucket, waf_key)
```

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event,context)

    waf_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    
    waf_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    print("BucketName: {}, Key: {}".format(waf_bucket, waf_key))
    print("Processing File: {}".format(waf_key))
    readObj = get_object(waf_bucket, waf_key)
    print(readObj)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please clarify where ```get_object``` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your code I can understand that you are trying to get object from s3. So you should have created an instance for s3 client above the lambda_handler function. The below code must solve your problem.

```
client = boto3.client('s3')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event,context)

    waf_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']

    waf_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    print("BucketName: {}, Key: {}".format(waf_bucket, waf_key))
    print("Processing File: {}".format(waf_key))
    readObj = client.get_object(waf_bucket, waf_key)
    print(readObj)
```